# Issue in migrating trac to redmine-2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rubygems, redmine

Try to migrate trac .11 to redmine as mentioned in http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-migrate-from-trac-to-redmine.  i tried to install gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter
but it also throw error "ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository"  , installing the alternative will throw the same issue

```
user@user:~/redmine-2.3$ rake redmine:migrate_from_trac RAILS_ENV="production" --trac
** Invoke redmine:migrate_from_trac (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute redmine:migrate_from_trac

WARNING: a new project will be added to Redmine during this process.
Are you sure you want to continue ? [y/N] y

Trac directory []: /home/sree/mytracproject
Trac database adapter (sqlite3, mysql2, postgresql) [sqlite3]: 
Trac database encoding [UTF-8]: 
Target project identifier []: mytracproject

This project already exists in your Redmine database.
Are you sure you want to append data to this project ? [Y/n] y

rake aborted!
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gem install sqlite3

The issue was that the gem file is not updating with "sqlite3"

In GEM FILE manually updated as

```
gem "sqlite3","1.3.8"
```

in redmine/Gemfile